# Create a complex CGRect

Tags: ios, cgrect, setneedsdisplayinrect

I have a view with a border of 10 pixels drawn on the    method.
I need to update the border color and I use `[self setNeedsDisplay]` to make it redraw
the view.
Since I need to update only the border I want to use : `[self setNeedsDisplayInRect:rect]` so it will draw only the border.

How can I get a rect of only the border with out the other areas of the view?

Thanks
Shani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't because a `CGRect` is rectangle, so it is a convex shape that can't have holes in it.

But you can decompose the border into four rectangles and call `[self setNeedsDisplayInRect:rect]` four times.

Also, if you import `QuartzCore`, you can probably use the property `borderColor` of the view's layer:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

// ...

view.layer.borderWidth = 10;
view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

// And to change it later
view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could get four CGRects around each part of the border (top, right, bottom, and left) and call the method four times with each of them.